# How to run mssql server dependent application to mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, mysql-workbench, c#

I am very new in mysql workbench. I have created an application in c# which uses sql server 2008 r2 database. Now i have migrated my database on mysql workbench. i want to run my application now.
My Question is is this the correct way of doing it or i have to redesign my app from starting just because of mysql workbench.
Second thing is, If it works than i want to replicate a table from sql server database to Mysql workbench database. Is it possible? If Yes than How? and if Not than what will be other way to do it?

Please help me. i am  stucked very badly here.

Thanks in Advance.......

Comment: If you are using C# and SQL Server 2008 R2, why on earth are you trying to use MySQL Workbench, designed for a completely different platform and stack? If you were writing code in fortran, would you try to use PowerBuilder or XMLSpy?

Comment: You may also find Oracle's SQL Developer to be an equally ineffective tool for managing Sql Server 2008R2.

Comment: I'm voting-to-close this as "too localized" since the question and answer are very unlikely to help any future visitor.  Moving a database from SQL Server to MySQL just so you can use MySQL toolset is unbearable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Management Studio is the tool you should probably be using to manage a SQL Server database. You can download `SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU.exe` from here:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43351

For the C# side, you could use Visual Studio:

http://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs#d-express-windows-desktop

Comment: But only mysql workbench is installed on server which i host my application

Comment: MySQL WorkBench is not going to help you; you will need to install other software.

Comment: But Database migration is possible in Mysql WorkBench and i have migrated it.

Comment: @user3346501 what on god's green earth are you talking about? You migrated to a MySQL instance? Why would you need to migrate your 2008R2 instance to begin with? Just use SQL Server Management Studio to manage your instance.

Comment: @user3346501 So MySQL Workbench allowed you to migrate your database to SQL Server? Great. Now you expect it to *manage* SQL Server, **and** your C# app *too*? I don't think those were on their feature list. If US Airways overbooks and puts me on a Delta flight, I don't expect a US Airways flight attendant to serve me beverages.

Comment: My guess is that MySQL Workbench analyzed your MySQL database, and produced a .sql script that you could run on SQL Server to *create* a new database based on the old database. This is hardly "migrating" and certainly not "managing."

Comment: Ok, So it will not work. But if i redesign my app using mysql database than how can i replicate my data from sql server 2008 database

Comment: @user3346501 You're going to migrate your data back to MySQL just because the only tool installed is MySQL Workbench?

Comment: Are you seriously suggesting you convert your SQL Server Database to MySQL just to us MySQL Workbench and then what, migrate it back so it can interface with your app?! Explain yourself?!